# Determine Computer's Internet Connection

Tags: proxy, network-programming, ip-address, vpn, internet-connection

I want to know how a website/program would determine the name/ID of my internet connection (are they reading my IP address?). Also, would a proxy/VPN prevent them from reading the ID of my internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A network connection, or more generally a network flow, can be identified by a tuple of fields fetched from the packet's header. Usually, more than one field is necessary. In TCP the quadruple formed by *{destination IP, destination port, source IP, source port}* can unequivocally identify a connection.

Being behind a proxy, let's say a NAT, doesn't really matter much in terms of how to identify a connection. The same mechanism applies. The difference is that the destination host sees the proxied source address. It's the proxy's responsibility to deliver incoming packets to the right destination.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Diego Pino       . To cut to the point, I want to visit a website with my internet connection ID = A; Then, I want to switch my Internet connection = B and go back to the aforementioned website. Any idea how I would do so?